# How to pass always used properties from controller to other classes in MVC?

Tags: php, class, model, controller

I'm currently improving my own MVC and I can't find a nice solution for the following scenario:
In most of my models I'm working with a few (already validated by another model) user-based inputs and need to pass them from the controller (where I basically tell the models what to do with the input) to the various models of course. At the moment I'm putting every single user input into a property:

```
    foreach($this->properties as $property => $empty)
    {
        if(isset($_POST[$property]))
        {
            $this->properties[$property] = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST[$property]));
        }
    }
```

Eventually when I need a new model to do something, I call it like this:

```
    new view('calendar',$data,$this->properties);
```

And finally in the model I receive the input / variables by putting them in the models properties…

```
class validation
{   

    public function __construct($values)
    {
        foreach($values as $property => $value)
        {
            $this->{$property} = $value;
        }
    }
}
```

That way I never have to think about where a variable comes from (after the user input has been validated, I don't really care anymore) and can always write a for me clean to read version of `$this->user_input`

But I somehow have the feeling that this is not the easiest way and propably not a good one either. What bothers me the most is that when writing a new class/model, I always have to tell the model to take the input into their own property and I always have to pass parameters when calling a new class.

Is there some way where I can just inherit these variables from the user when a new class is getting called without having the controller to be a parent class - or would this actually make sense to make the controller a parent? I think it would be confusing when another controller uses the model.

Comment: Why are you using `htmlspecialchars(trim())` in places where you are not displaying the data?

Comment: Later on these user inputs will be displayed and that way I don't have to do it again and again when displaying it, also it doesn't make a difference when working with those variables.

Comment: You know what MVC stands for / is about right? Separation of concerns. At least don't call it MVC when it is not :)

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get it. What speaks against using `htmlspecialchars(trim())` in a controller in regards to MVC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok the big thing to remember here, is that your controller "**has a**" variable container (holding all your properties), as opposed to the controller being (or "**is a**") a variable container. So first thing, you should be using composition, and **not** inheritance.

The following snippets below are commented to explain in more detail. Some notes:

- The InputData instance could be created above the controller level (say, in a different controller, so that is can be shared among many controllers) which answers the main part of your question. The key point is you're only writing it once, and you can safely say once it's in there, it's good to go
- You can include all validation methods inside the InputData, as the role of InputData is to house/store the data safely - which in my opinion a good level of abtraction, or in other words "it's responsible for input data, if something is wrong with the input data, I know where to look"
- Finally, for a little extra shine, I added some bit operations so when adding values through the input_data->add, they could be validated against multiple types (for example something could be added which needs to be validated as both a number and a post code).

**index.php**

```
require_once( "Controller.php" );

$controller = new Controller();
$controller->print_current_user();
```

**Controller.php**

```
<?
require_once( "Input_Data.php" );

class Controller 
{
    // Variables    
    private $input_data;

    // Models
    // private $model_user;

    public function __construct() 
    {
        $this->input_data = new Input_Data();
        //$this->model_user = new Model_User();

        // Process input (might not happen in the constructor,
        // in fact, it might happen higher up, so it can be shared

        // Possibly looping over GET / POST data
        // for each one, add it to the inputData
        $_GET[ 'name' ] = 'Chris';
        $_GET[ 'country' ] = 'Australia';        

        // example iteration 1        
        $this->input_data->add( 'name', $_GET[ 'name' ], Input_Data::TYPE_VALIDATE_NAME | Input_Data::TYPE_VALIDATE_TEXT );
        // example iteration 2
        $this->input_data->add( 'country', $_GET[ 'country' ], Input_Data::TYPE_VALIDATE_COUNTRY );
    }

    // later on in controller, model needs to find the user by name
    public function print_current_user() 
    {
        // Example Usage to Model:
        // $this->$model_user->get_by_name( $this->input_data->get( 'name' ) );
        //
        // For now, we'll settle with just printing it out
        echo $this->input_data->get( 'name' );
    }
}
?>
```

**Input Data**

```
<?
class Input_Data 
{
    const TYPE_VALIDATE_TEXT = 0;
    const TYPE_VALIDATE_NAME = 1;
    const TYPE_VALIDATE_EMAIL = 2;
    const TYPE_VALIDATE_ADDRESS = 4;
    const TYPE_VALIDATE_COUNTRY = 8;

    protected $data;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->data = array();
    }

    public function add( $name, $value, $type )
    {
        if( $type & TYPE_VALIDATE_TEXT )        
        {
            // validate input as text
            // if valid, flag as such, to be inserted
            // or alternatively return a safe version
            // depending on your application, an empty string
        }    
        if( $type & TYPE_VALIDATE_NAME )        
        {
            // validate input as name
        }
        if( $type & TYPE_VALIDATE_EMAIL )        
        {
            // validate input as email
        }    
        if( $type & TYPE_VALIDATE_ADDRESS )        
        {
            // validate input as address
        }    
        if( $type & TYPE_VALIDATE_COUNTRY )        
        {
            // validate input as country
        }    

        // If its valid or is now santised
        // insert into the $data variable
        // if( $valid ) {
        $this->data[ $name ] = $value;
        // }
        // data[ name ] now contains a safe value that can be accessed
    }

    public function get( $name )
    {
        // do checking to ensure it exists
        // then return it
        return $this->data[ $name ];
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Although nearly all the earlier answers pointed me in the same direction, you made it most clear for me so I could understand the scheme! Thanks everybody for the answers! aloha

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your needs, it may make sense to store the user inputs in a property of a [singleton class](http://www.talkphp.com/advanced-php-programming/1304-how-use-singleton-design-pattern.html) (e.g. a UserRequest class):

```
class UserRequest extends Singleton
{
    protected $userProperties;
    public function getUserProperties()
    {
        return $this->userProperties;
    }
    ...other methods...
}
```

In your bootstrap or routing class, when you capture the user inputs, save them in your Request instance, and then have all controllers extend a base class that reads this property:

```
class baseController
{
    protected $userProperties;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->userProperties = Request::getInstance()->getUserProperties();
    }
}
```

Then all controllers will have access to it, and you only have to capture it once.

Answer (score 1):

I think a better solution is to store all the inputs in an object lets just call it `data`. Each of the models can have a `data` property. After the controller has completed input validation you can pass the object to the first model and store it there. At that point you can freely pass the object around from model to model. If you're changing values in `data` you should later update the controllers object with a method call like `$this->data = $Model->GetData();` or whatever.

With the MVC paradigm it's not sensible to have models accessing properties of the controller. The controller should basically be initiating all communications ie the controller passes the data to the model who does operations on it, then the controller requests that data and puts it in the view. It would not be good practice to have the controller holding the data and the model operating on it directly.

Answer (score 1):

> What bothers me the most is that when writing a new class/model, I always have to tell the model to take the input into their own property and I always have to pass parameters when calling a new class.

So let's say you have two problems here:

1. Repetition to define properties per each class definition.
2. Passing parameters for each class creation.

In the most bare and basic sense, you can not circumvent both. If you won't tell the class (at least *somehow*) which properties it represents, it wouldn't know. Somewhat similar for the second point, if the data is not set to the class, it won't work.

So as it is technically not possible to prevent these two at all, the question is how to make it more comfortable and reduce repetition - if possible.

One route to go would be to just take all these objects to be of the same type. I mean actually those are just some improved arrays, aren't they?

So you can create yourself a base-class you can extend from that contains all the needed code, like importing an array, defining the properties.

So you only need to write the code once and create as many objects and different "types" as you want.

Some example, let's create one such object that has a base-class that does it's job:

```
class TestModel extends SelfDefinedVariableObjectBase
{
    protected $properties = ['bar' => 'hello world'];
}
```

That's it.Object defined. Now let's use it:

```
// $_POST['bar'] = '<h1>test</h1> let\'s throw some HTML in';

$foo = new TestModel($_POST);
echo $foo->bar, "\n";
```

This does import some data from `$_POST` that is matching with the objects properties (similar to what you have). However the output is the same:

```
<h1>test</h1> let's throw some HTML in
```

You might now want that. So therefore you can create some decorators for example, here one that works with a callback function:

```
class VariableObjectCallbackDecorator
{
    private $subject;
    private $callback;

    public function __construct(VariableObjectBase $object, callable $callback) {
        $this->subject = $object;
        $this->callback = $callback;
    }
    public function __get($name) {
        return call_user_func($this->callback, $this->subject->__get($name));
    }
}
```

Let's use it with the test-object from the previous example:

```
$bar = new VariableObjectCallbackDecorator($foo, 'htmlspecialchars');
echo $bar->bar, "\n";
```

And now this time the output is:

```
&lt;h1&gt;test&lt;/h1&gt; let's throw some HTML in
```

Hope this is helpful. You can find the code here: [Demo](http://eval.in/5459)

Answer (score -1):

> would this actually make sense to make the controller a parent?

Yes, that is probably exactly how I would do it.  Then you can use *protected* for the properties you want to share/inherit.

Comment: Could you refer to my other quote " I think it would be confusing when another controller uses the model." too please??

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why it would be confusing.  Based on what we see here, there would be no confusion (at least not for me ;-)

Comment: I'd have to define the name of each controller in the model. So I'd always have to edit each model that gets used when I'm writing a new controller/parent...